# How to check this Json response whether its null or not

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"PatientPastMedicalHistoryGetResult":{"PastMedicalHistory":[]}}
```

The PastMedicalHistory array is NUll without values. How can i check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (response.PatientPastMedicalHistoryGetResult.PastMedicalHistory.length == 0) {

}
```

And this isn't null. This is an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have null in response, Try

```
   var data = {"PatientPastMedicalHistoryGetResult":{"PastMedicalHistory":[]}};

    for (member in data) {
        if (data[member] != null)
            // Do work here
    }
```